# MJAndroid installation giving errors

Tags: android, eclipse, target

I am a beginner with Eclipse. I downloaded the code from [this link](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596521509/).

After importing the project I get this error-

> Unable to get system library for the project.

I have searched around this website and have encountered similar questions posted by users.
Most replies have been that changing the Target helps. But the Target options are available in 2.2 and 2.3.1 only. And after selecting a Target, selecting Okay, and reopening the Properties Tab, both options are unchecked.
I'm totally clueless, kindly help.
Another thing, in the book it says we need a Map API, and asks me to tap in some commands on the terminal. Where exactly am I supposed to type in the commands?